# How to scale out a Kubernetes Cluster based on allocatable resources?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

I am looking for an opportunity to add a new worker node to my `kubernetes` cluster when its allocatable resources falls below a specified minimum.

To scale out a cluster automatically I found the [cluster-autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler). But the documentation says, it only scales out, if:

> there are pods that failed to run in the cluster due to insufficient resources

Therefore a new node gets started only after a pod is in `pending` state. The startup of a new node takes about 2 minutes and I would like to avoid a pending time of 2 minutes for a pod.

Comment: The only solution comes to my head is monitoring the resources manually and once they drop bellow set threshold add new worker node.

Comment: What is causing a new pod to be created?  Are you using a horizontal pod scaler?  If so, what metrics is it based on?

Comment: @erk When I asked this question I wanted to use a horizontal pod scaler, but also was looking for a good way to scale the cluster.